# How to dispatch message to several destination with apache camel?

Tags: http, apache-camel

My problematic seem to be simple, but I haven't find yet a way to solve it...

I have a legacy system which is working and a new system which will replace it. This is only rest webservices call, so I'm using simple bridge endpoint on http service.

To ensure the iso-functional run, I want to put them behind a camel route dispatching message to both system but returning only the response of the legacy one and log the response of both system to be sure there are running in same way...

I create this route :

```
   from("servlet:proxy?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
        .streamCaching()
        .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", header("CamelHttpMethod"))
        .to("log:com.mylog?showAll=true&multiline=true&showStreams=true")
        .multicast()
        .to(urlServer1 + "?bridgeEndpoint=true")
        .to(urlServer2 + "?bridgeEndpoint=true")
        .to("log:com.mylog?showAll=true&multiline=true&showStreams=true")
    ;
```

It works to call each services and to log messages, but response are in a mess...

If the first server doesn't respond, the second is not call, if the second respond an error, only that error is send back to client...

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 3):

You can check for some more details in multicast docs http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html

Default behaviour of multicast (your case) is:

- parallelProcessing is false so routes are called one by one

To correctly implement your case you need probably:

- add error handling for each external service call so exception will not stop correct processing
- configure or implement some aggregator strategy and put it to the strategyRef so you can combine results from all calls to the single multicast result